# Problem with loop every 2 columns, with copy paste formula from different sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have this loop, where I try to copy a formula in one row, from one sheet to another, and then copy paste the same formula in all rows in the first sheet. The loop does not copy paste the formula, and I think it's the copy part where I'm off.

Somebody can help me out?

Here is what I have.

I would expect that the formula from the chosen column, on the first row will be copied to all rows in the same column in a different sheet.

```
So i've managed to create the wanted code, by the following code (without the loop):

Dim startcell, startcell2, startcell3, startcell4, startcell5 As Range, lastrow, lastrow2, lastrow3, lastrow4, lastrow5 As Long, ws As Worksheet, pastebook, formula As Worksheet


Set formula = Sheet3
Set startcellformula = formula.Range("BI8")
Set startcellformula2 = formula.Range("BK8")
Set startcellformula3 = formula.Range("BO8")
Set startcellformula4 = formula.Range("BQ8")
Set startcellformula5 = formula.Range("BS8")
Set startcellformula6 = formula.Range("BU8")
Set startcellformula7 = formula.Range("BW8")
Set startcellformula8 = formula.Range("BY8")
Set startcellformula9 = formula.Range("CA8")
Set startcellformula10 = formula.Range("CC8")
Set startcellformula11 = formula.Range("CE8")
Set startcellformula12 = formula.Range("CG8")
Set startcellformula13 = formula.Range("CI8")

lastrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, startcell.Column).End(xlUp).Row


startcellformula.Copy
pastebook.Range("BI8:BI" & lastrow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlFormulas
startcellformula.Copy
pastebook.Range("BK8:BK" & lastrow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlFormulas
startcellformula.Copy
pastebook.Range("BO8:BO" & lastrow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlFormulas
startcellformula.Copy
pastebook.Range("BQ8:BQ" & lastrow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlFormulas
startcellformula.Copy
pastebook.Range("BS8:BS" & lastrow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlFormulas
startcellformula.Copy
pastebook.Range("BU8:BU" & lastrow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlFormulas
startcellformula.Copy
pastebook.Range("BW8:BW" & lastrow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlFormulas
startcellformula.Copy
pastebook.Range("BY8:BY" & lastrow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlFormulas
startcellformula.Copy
pastebook.Range("CA8:CA" & lastrow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlFormulas
startcellformula.Copy
pastebook.Range("CC8:CC" & lastrow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlFormulas
startcellformula.Copy
pastebook.Range("CE8:CE" & lastrow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlFormulas
startcellformula.Copy
pastebook.Range("CG8:CG" & lastrow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlFormulas
startcellformula.Copy
pastebook.Range("CI8:CI" & lastrow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlFormulas

I've tried to work a bit more on the loop, and this where I am currently. I think the only steps left is some syntax. 

'Copy formulas in every other Column between BH and CI
Set startcolumn = Range("BI8").Cells
Set Endcolumn = pastebook.Column("BI")
Set startcellformula = formula.Range(startcolumn)
For currCol = pastebook.Columns("BI").Column To pastebook.Columns("CI").Column Step 2
For startcolumn = pastebook.Columns(startcolumn).Column To currCol Step 2
For Endcolumn = pastebook.Columns(Endcolumn).Column To currCol Step 2
startcellformula.Copy
pastebook.Range(startcolumn, pastebook.Range(startcolumn & Endcolumn & lastrow)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlFormulas

Next Endcolumn
Next startcolumn
Next currCol
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You do `Set pastebook = Sheet1` and then later on you do `pastbook.currCol`. You are missing char `e`. Also, always use `Option Explicit` at start of codes, so your vars are forced to be defined. Also, debug your code with F8 and check what line fails.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome!

First of all this `pastbook.currCol` should be `pastebook.currCol`.

Second, this `currCol` will return a number, so this `pastebook.currCol` doesn't really make any sense anyway.

Instead of `pastebook.currCol`, which will give you an error saying "Object doesn't support this method.", you need a `range`.

Not sure which `range` you want to use. That depends on what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks so much for your feedback.
I'm trying to copy the formulas in BI8 into another sheet, same column (BI8), and I wan to do this in every other column until column CI8. But I only have the formula in the first row (BI8), so I just wanted to copy BI8 formula into the range of BI8 and all rows below (defined by lastrow). What do I miss?

Comment: @sag As I said this `currCol = Columns("BI").Column` will return a number of type `Long`. So `currCol` should be declared as Long. In this case it's going to be `currCol =61`. So your loop basically is going to be equivalent to `For currCol=61 to 87 step 2`. Now, `formula.Range()` takes two arguments of type `Range`. You are using it with one `Range` argument, being `startcellformula` and one argument that doesn't make any sense at all, being `pastebook.currCol`. It's like writing `pastebook.61`, which is going to give an error by default. You need to change `pastebook.currCol` to a `Range`.

Comment: @sag Also, what's `startcell`? The way you are using it, it's supposed to be a `Range`, but it's neither declared nor `set` to anything. Your code is missing too much info. Please consider revising it, so I can help you.

Comment: Hi again,

So i've managed to create the wanted code, by the following code (without the loop):